# Error received whilst executing COPY statement in Azure Synapse Analytics for csv.gz file using GZIP codec

Tags: azure, csv, gzip, azure-synapse

I have a [COPY INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) statement which loads a csv.gz file from a blob storage account into an Azure Synapse instance that fails repetitively after almost exactly one hour (01:00:08) with the error message below;

`Error occurred while decoding 'https://somestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.csv.gz' using GZIP codec. Codec error code: -5. Codec error message: <unknown>`

I'm using a service principal as a credential to execute the script ([followed this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql-examples#e-service-principal-authentication)) as below;

```
COPY INTO [Schema].[tbTable]
FROM 'https://somestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.csv.gz'
WITH  (
    CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY= 'xxx-123-abc@https://login.microsoftonline.com/abc-xxx-123/oauth2/token', SECRET='123-secretvalue-xxx'),
    FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',
    COMPRESSION = 'GZIP',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    ENCODING = 'UTF8',
    FIRSTROW = 2
);
```

I have tested this script with the credential set as the storage account key and I do not encounter the same problem. I would prefer to have a service principal set to execute the script.

I'm suspicious of the script repetitively failing after one hour (timeout?). Is this likely to be a service principal permissions issue? I can't find anything to suggest that there is a timeout for processes issued using this identity.

Comment: Suggestions would be to 1.comment out the Compression and Encoding as this is inferred based on filetype and that the file endswith .gz  2. Also try changing the FIELDQUOTE to an empty string, this will ensure that all characters within the fields are ingested, as follows `FIELDQUOTE = '',`  3. Since Copy INTO is new since last year, there could be some trail and error to configure this just right.

Answer (score 2):

I did eventually get an answer from a Microsoft Azure Synapse Analytics Support Escalation Engineer. The response was that App tokens have a TTL of 1 hour and therefore the reason why my script was failing.

Microsoft engineer response below;

Find below a case summary of what we have worked together, so you can save for future references.

- **Symptom**: A COPY INTO statement which loads a csv.gz file from a blob    storage account into SQL DW instance that fails repetitively after    almost exactly one hour (01:00:08) with the error message below;

  - Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 13820. Error
    Message: Error occurred while decoding
    'https://somestorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.csv.gz'
    using GZIP codec. Codec error code: -5. Codec error message: unknown
- **Cause**: *After syncing with someone from AAD we confirmed that App    tokens have a TTL of 1 hour*. Internal MS tenants, like the one we    used to test, have custom 24 hours TTL configured. This inconsistency  is what caused the confusion. Unfortunately, the native code path in DW (openrowset backend) does not support Refreshing of tokens, so the  1-hr is a hard limit. There is an improvement in the backlog for    this.

Couple options for cx:

- Use another auth method like MSI, if possible. Per AAD folks, MSI    tokens all have TTL's of 24 hours, internal or external.
- AAD tenant admin, can configure token lifetimes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties-after-the-retirement

Comment: Thanks for coming back with that useful info Kevin.